# Why give a non-useful example of blowing a Shofar on Shabbat in Shulchan Aruch 307:5?

Tags: halacha, shulchan-aruch

In סימן תקפח - זמן תקיעת שופר the Mechaber codifies that one does not blow the Shofar on Shabbat.

> **ה:** יוֹם טוֹב שֶׁל רֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה שֶׁחָל לִהְיוֹת  בְּשַׁבָּת אֵין תּוֹקְעִין בְּשׁוֹפָר. *הגה: וְאָסוּר לְטַלְטְלוֹ, אִם לֹא לְצֹרֶךְ  גּוּפוֹ וּמְקוֹמוֹ (אוֹר זָרוּעַ וְהַגָּהוֹת אֲשֵׁרִי סוֹף פֶּרֶק בַּמֶּה מַּדְלִיקִין)*.‏

So why is it that in סימן שז - דיני שבת התלוים בדבור when **the Mechaber gives an example of something permissible you may ask a non-Jew to do on Shabbat** because it's a Mitzvah, he chooses: *one may ask the non-Jew to **climb a tree to bring a Shofar** to fulfil the Mitzvah of blowing the Shofar.*

> **ה:** דָּבָר שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְלָאכָה, וְאֵינוֹ אָסוּר לַעֲשׂוֹת בְּשַׁבָּת אֶלָּא מִשּׁוּם שְׁבוּת, מֻתָּר לְיִשְׂרָאֵל לוֹמַר לְעַכּוּ''ם לַעֲשׂוֹתוֹ בְּשַׁבָּת; וְהוּא שֶׁיִּהְיֶה שָׁם מִקְצָת חֹלִי, אוֹ יִהְיֶה צָרִיךְ לַדָּבָר צֹרֶךְ הַרְבֵּה, אוֹ מִפְּנֵי מִצְוָה; כֵּיצַד: **אוֹמֵר יִשְׂרָאֵל לְעַכּוּ''ם בְּשַׁבָּת לַעֲלוֹת בָּאִילָן לְהָבִיא שׁוֹפָר לִתְקֹעַ תְּקִיעַת מִצְוָה**; אוֹ לְהָבִיא מַיִם דֶּרֶךְ חָצֵר שֶׁלֹּא עֵרְבוֹ, לִרְחֹץ בּוֹ הַמִּצְטַעֵר; וְיֵשׁ אוֹסְרִין. *הגה: וּלְקַמָּן סי' תקפ''ו פָּסַק לְהַתִּיר, וְעַיֵּן לְעֵיל (ז) סי' רע''ו (ס''ב) דְּיֵשׁ מְקִלִּין אֲפִלּוּ בִּמְלָאכָה דְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, (וְע''ש ס''ג)*. ‏

While this may have been a great example for Yom Tov or for when they used to blow on Shabbat, **why not give a more useful example - one that can be implemented nowadays?**

Comment: Wasn't the Mechaber involved in the Mahari Beirav's semicha attempt?  Maybe he thought it would be relevant in his time.

Comment: @heshy interesting theory...

Comment: Am I not understanding something, here? In the 2nd citation, the part that you bolded, He says that on Shabbat, one can tell a Gentile to get the Shofar because it's a mitzvah. Huh? You can't blow the Shofar on Shabbat, anyway! How is it a mitzvah to blow shofar then?

Comment: @DanF - that's what I'm asking! Why bring a "wrong" example?

Comment: OK. I was a bit confused about that, myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that was the example that the Rambam gave here, and the Shulchan Aruch will often follow the Rambam's language.  This is helpful because Rambam holds that in a place of Beis Din Kavuah, Shofar would be blown on Shabbos even nowadays.  (Based on this, the Kaf Hachaim here suggests that the words "on Shabbos" are not exact, and can be read as on Rosh Hashana, and in fact, many authorities make similar corrections).

---

Being that you might not like the above answer, I will note that this is asked by a few other Acharonim.  R' Yaakov Emden in Mor Uketziah here is astonished that he could not find anyone who addressed it, and does not provide an answer:

> שם. כתב הרמב"ם שאמירה לגוי מותרת בשבות שיש בו (קצת)2 צורך מצוה כגון שא"ל לעלות באילן להביא שופר כו'. דברים הללו תמוהים הם וצריך לדחוק מאד ליישבם, אפילו אליבא דרמב"ם, דנסיב נמי מאי דלא נהיג האידנא (כמ"ש בס"ד בהגהותי לחבורו פ"ו מהל' שבת). מ"מ על הטור תמיהא קיימת, כ"ש הש"ע דאכפל וטרח למכתב מידי דלא צריך לן לגמרי, (ואין) [ואף] אחד מהאחרונים לא חלי ולא מרגיש.

The Machatzis Hashekel suggests that this takes place when Rosh Hashana is on Sunday, and the non-Jew is bringing it to be blown on the following day.  Note that this opens a completely different Halachic discussion, which I will not go in to here.

> ודע, דלפי מה שכתב בשו"ע, וכן כתב הרמב"ם [שבת ו, י], אומר ישראל לגוי בשבת לעלות באילן להביא שופר, והא קיימא לן [סימן תקפח סעיף ה] דתקיעת שופר לדידן לא דחי שבת, על כרחך צריך לומר דמיירי שחל ראש השנה יום שבת ויום א' שאחריו, ומביאו לצורך יום א' שהוא יום שני של ראש השנה.

Comment: @msh210 Here's what the Piskei Teshuvos says:  ובכה"ח (סקמ"ז) כתב שלשון שו"ע 'בשבת' לאו דווקא הוא, אלא העתיק דברי הרמב"ם (פ"ו ה"ט), ולהרמב"ם (בפ"ב מהל' תקיעת שופר) גם בזמן הזה תוקעין בשופר בכל מקום שיש בית דין קבוע, ואכן בטור ובלבוש הכא אין כתוב 'בשבת', ובשו"ע הרב (סעי' י"ב) מתקנו להדיא "לעלות באילן בראש השנה"

Comment: I guess I have to accept apparently "weak" answers. As Shulchan Aruch is written much later than Ramba"m, I would think that the author would have edited something that wasn't relevant at that time.

Comment: @DanF, I accepted the answer not because of the *Rambam quotation* (which I suspected, and is *the real answer*) but because of the 2nd half. (Yes, I'm convoluted.)